# Can Expandable ListView be Inside ListView

Tags: android

can we have ExpandableListView inside ListView so that I can have group level first and then child items.
Only ExpandableListView is group and child, I want to have an ExpandableListView Inside ListView. 
Tried with open source TreeView but could not get specifically all those features of ExpandableListView.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Comment: I am not agree with your terms that you want expandable listview inside ListView, because **Expandable listview itself a listview** with particular item expands whenever you click on it.

Comment: Initially make all items of Expandalbe ListView as collapsed, expand it whenever user clicks on it by [onChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html).

Comment: Check this example for what i am saying: http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpandableListView itself is ListView, you can not use ExpandableListView inside ListView...

Answer (score 0):

But you can achieve the need of functionality of the same without the ListView. Here is the code for the same.

ExpandableListView adapter code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    /**
     * Holds the mapping details
     */
    Mapdetail mMapDetials = new Mapdetail();
    /**
     * Holds the contest
     */
    private Context mContext;
    /**
     * Holds tehe xpandable list VIew
     */
    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    /**
     * Holds the details for the cards
     */
    private List<com.sourcebits.sfc.activity.GroupEntity> mGroupCollection;
    /**
     * Holds the status whether its expanded or not
     */
    private int[] groupStatus;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context pContext,
            ExpandableListView pExpandableListView,
            List<com.sourcebits.sfc.activity.GroupEntity> mGroupCollection2) {
        mContext = pContext;
        mGroupCollection = mGroupCollection2;
        mExpandableListView = pExpandableListView;
        groupStatus = new int[mGroupCollection.size()];
        setListEvent();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the event listeners
     */
    private void setListEvent() {

        mExpandableListView
                .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {
                        groupStatus[arg0] = 1;
                    }
                });

        mExpandableListView
                .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGroupCollapse(int arg0) {
                        groupStatus[arg0] = 0;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public String getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.get(arg1).Name;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int arg0, final int arg1, boolean arg2,
            View arg3, ViewGroup arg4) {

        ChildHolder childHolder;
        if (arg3 == null) {
            arg3 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_group_item, null);

            childHolder = new ChildHolder();

            childHolder.title = (TextView) arg3.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            childHolder.background = (ImageView) arg3
                    .findViewById(R.id.background);

            arg3.setTag(childHolder);
        } else {
            childHolder = (ChildHolder) arg3.getTag();
        }

        if (arg1 == 0) {
            childHolder.background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_top);
        } else {
            childHolder.background
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_bottom);
        }

        childHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mMapDetials.setmLanguageIndex(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection
                        .get(arg1).Name);
                startNextActivity();
            }
        });
        childHolder.title
                .setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection
                        .get(arg1).Name);

        return arg3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
        return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        return mGroupCollection.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mGroupCollection.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int arg0, boolean arg1, View arg2,
            ViewGroup arg3) {

        GroupHolder groupHolder;
        if (arg2 ==     null) {
            arg2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_group,
                    null);
            groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
            groupHolder.img = (ImageView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.tag_img);
            groupHolder.title = (TextView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.group_title);
            arg2.setTag(groupHolder);
        } else {
            groupHolder = (GroupHolder) arg2.getTag();
        }
        if (groupStatus[arg0] == 0) {
            groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_expand);
        } else {

            mMapDetials.setTrainingPointIndex(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).Name);
            groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_collapse);
        }
        groupHolder.img.setTag("NotClicked");
        if (mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.size() == 0) {
            groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
            mMapDetials.setmLanguageIndex("English");
            groupHolder.img.setTag("Clicked");
            groupHolder.img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (v.getTag().toString().equals("Clicked")) {
                        mMapDetials.setTrainingPointIndex(mGroupCollection
                                .get(arg0).Name);
                        startNextActivity();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

        groupHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).Name);

        return arg2;
    }

    /**
     * Holds the view of the parent
     * 
     * @author Gautam Balasubramanian
     * 
     */
    class GroupHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView title;
    }

    /**
     * ChildHolder class view of the child view
     * 
     * @author Gautam Balasubramanian
     * 
     */
    class ChildHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView background;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return true;
    }

    void startNextActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GeneralInfo.class);
        mMapDetials.toString();
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putSerializable("values", mMapDetials);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Code to call from the activty:

```
private void initPage() {
    mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    mExpandableListView.setCacheColorHint(0);
    ExpandableListAdapterforProducts adapter = new ExpandableListAdapterforProducts(
            Products.this, mExpandableListView, mGroupCollection);

    mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ColorDrawable sage = new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(
            R.color.sage));
    mExpandableListView.setDivider(sage);
    mExpandableListView.setDividerHeight(1);
}
```

Initailisation of values,

```
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SqliteAdapterForProducts(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
    mCursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueProducts();
    Log.v("", mCursor.getCount() + "is the count");
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    mGroupCollection = new ArrayList<GroupEntity>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {
        GroupEntity groupEntity = new GroupEntity();
        groupEntity.Name = mCursor.getString(1) + "  "
                + mCursor.getString(2);

        String languages[] = mCursor.getString(3).toString().split(",");
        if (languages.length > 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < languages.length; j++) {
                GroupItemEntity groupItemEntity = groupEntity.new GroupItemEntity();
                groupItemEntity.Name = languages[j];
                groupEntity.GroupItemCollection.add(groupItemEntity);
            }
        }

        mCursor.moveToNext();
        mGroupCollection.add(groupEntity);
    }

    mCursor.close();
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

The above stuff worked for me. You can try it.